# Algorithm to determine the maximum profit from buying and selling items based on the best offers in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, loops, dictionary, sorting

Suppose we have a dictionary called book which contains two sub-dictionaries "buy" and "sell". Each sub-dictionary contains key-value pairs where the key represents the price and the value represents the quantity. For example, book['buy'][11.40] = 7000 means that there are 7000 items available to buy at the price of 11.40. Similarly, book['sell'][20.30] = 5500 means that there are 5500 items available to sell at the price of 20.30.

To calculate the profit from buying all the best offers in book['buy'] and selling them for the best price in book['sell'], we need to find the maximum profit we can make. The maximum profit is achieved by buying items at the lowest available price and selling them at the highest available price.

We can achieve this by first sorting the "buy" sub-dictionary in ascending order based on the price and then sorting the "sell" sub-dictionary in descending order based on the price. We can then iterate through both sub-dictionaries simultaneously and compare the prices. If the buy price is less than the sell price, we can buy the items and sell them at the higher price. We repeat this process until all the buy or sell offers are exhausted.

Here is an attempt at solving the problem, but it is not working correctly:

```py
bought_price = 0 
sold_price = 0
ordered_buy = dict(sorted(book['buy'].items())) # filtering buy from lowest to biggest
ordered_sell = dict(sorted(book["sell"].items(), reverse=True)) # filtering sell from big. to low.

for buy_price, buy_size in ordered_buy.items(): # starting with the best buy price
    for sell_price, sell_size in ordered_sell.items(): # going through all the sell offers
        if buy_price < sell_price:
            if buy_size == 0 or sell_size == 0:
                continue
            if buy_size < sell_size:
                ordered_buy[buy_price] = 0
                offer_rest = sell_price - buy_price
                ordered_sell[sell_price] = offer_rest
                bought_price += buy_price * buy_size  
                sold_price += sell_price * sell_size - sell_price * offer_rest
            elif buy_size > sell_size:
                ordered_sell[sell_price] = 0
                offer_rest = buy_price - sell_price
                ordered_buy[buy_price] = offer_rest
                bought_price += buy_price * buy_size - buy_price * offer_rest
                sold_price += sell_price * sell_size
```

Can anyone please suggest a solution to the problem or help me identify what is wrong with my approach?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: So you have reason to believe that there's something wrong with it, but you're not willing to tell us that reason?

Answer (score 1):

The issues in your code include:

1. your code misses the case where `buy_size` and `sell_size` are equal (and not zero). In that case your code skips that selling opportunity and looks for lesser prices... This is of course not optimal.

   To fix, change this:

   ```
    elif buy_size > sell_size:
   ```

   To just:

   ```
    else:
   ```
2. `offer_rest` is calculated wrong: it should not be the difference in **price**, but the difference in **size**.

   So in the `if` block change:

   ```
    offer_rest = sell_price - buy_price
   ```

   to:

   ```
    offer_rest = sell_size - buy_size
   ```

   ... and apply a similar change in the `else` block.

Comment: Not "the" problem but "one" problem.